# Missing characters in axis captions

Tags: graphics, errors

[image: Missing words in comments of a picture. They should be Accuracy and Fixed sum of RGB.]

I draw this picture with gnuplot. The x axis is the fixed sum of RGB and the y axis is accuracy. When I insert the picture by employing `subfigure` and `\includegraphics` some characters are missing.

Could anyone tell me know how to solve it?

My code is

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \subfigure[XX.]{
    \label{fig:shoulder_height} 
    \includegraphics[width=3.5in]{fig/6-4-color-difference.eps}}
  \vspace{0.1in}
  \caption{XX.}
  \vspace{-0.1in}
  \label{fig:accu_bodyfeature} 
\end{figure}
```

[The original eps picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wny4fvo3ivm0vh/6-4-color-difference.eps?dl=0)

Comment: Can you add your code and a downloadable version of your original picture?

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem using that EPS. You might want to provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet, plus information about your LaTeX system. BTW: ` \vspace{0.1in}`: learn to configure captions, it should never be necessary to manually add those.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `subfigure` package, which hasn't been maintained for may years. I suggest using the `subfigure` environment from  `subcaption`, and the `epstopdf` package to compile with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{3.5in}{
    \label{fig:shoulder_height}
    \includegraphics[width=3.5in]{6-4-color-difference.eps}}
 \caption{XX} \label{fig:accu_bodyfeature}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{YYYY.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]